# In firebase how can i give read access to multiple child values

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

here is my structure data

- sampleApp

  - items

    - item1

      - title: pizza
      - price: 200/-
    - item2

      - title :burger
      - price: 120/-
  - users

    - user-1

      - name: username
      - email:user@gmail.com
      - role

        - admin: true
        - user : true
        - superuser: true
    - user-2

      - name: username2
      - email: user2@gmail.com
      - role

        - admin: false
        - user: true
        - superuser: false

### Here is my rules

```
rules{
  ".write": true,
  "items":{
    ".read":"root.child(users).child(auth.uid).child(role).child(admin).val()===true"      
  }
}
```

My question is when user-1: " admin=true, user=true, superuser=true " total items child have to read. For another user-2: " admin=false, user=true, superuser=false " in this case only item1 has to read in items child.

How can I write the security rules for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my understanding, you would like to give read permission to any superuser **OR** admin.

You can use boolean logic in security rules like this:

```
rules{
   ".write": true,
   "items":{
      ".read":"root.child(users).child(auth.uid).child(role).child(admin).val()===true 
              ||"root.child(users).child(auth.uid).child(role).child(superuser).val()===true" "      
       }
    }
```

Hope it helps ;)